# Is it possible to trigger chrome to open a pdf versus to download it

Tags: browser, download

I am generating a pdf on the server that I would like browsers to attempt to open in-tab (those browsers that can do so) instead of downloading.

I was pretty sure that this is a matter of having or not having some header but I can't find it. Is it possible to control whether the user's browser displays or downloads your asset?

Comment: Did you [try specifying the `content-type`](http://superuser.com/a/515622)?

Comment: @admdrew or...maybe I was specifying the wrong content-type period because I had the wrong value in a constant. Nevermind the question then. The answer was `Content-Disposition` just like I thought

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat Reader X have a checkbox under Edit > Preferences > Internet to enable or disable in-browser view, regardless of the status of the browser plugin.

If that check is ok, or you have a more recent version, you can check if the plugin is active in you browser, every browser have different plugin.

A fast check is to open a local pdf file in your browser, something like file://localhost/C:/dir1/.../file.pdf, if Adobe Reader have the right check and the plugin is working the file will be showed in the browser otherwise, even if it is a local file, the browser will ask a folder to download it.

Answer (score 0):

So in my specific case I was sending the wrong `content-type` (thanks @admdrew for pointing me in the right direction) due to coding a constant wrong.

However, the answer is that there is indeed a header - at least when working with pdfs that will suggest to chrome at least whether it should open or download a file. [This header is `Content-Disposition`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1). In my case setting it:

```
Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = @"attachment; filename="foo.pdf"
```

triggered a download, while omitting it triggered in-page opening.

In addition, the above link states

> If this header is used in a response with the application/octet-
>   stream content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent
>   should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response
>   as...' dialog.

Though I found using `Content-Type: application/pdf` worked ok in both cases.